# Electrical Circuits Analysis Help

Tags: nodal-analysis

[image]

Am I correct? Or does D= V1-20, which allows the value of V1 to be positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, V1 minus 20 in equation makes more sense.

If V1 was negative that would mean current is going into node from each branch which is impossible due to KCL.